# statsmodels: tsa.api.predict() que debe devuelver un numero devuelve algo que es incomparable

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, casting

Tengo una serie de datos `ts`:

```
0    2599.0
1    2599.0
2    3998.0
3    3998.0
4    1299.0
5    1499.0
6    1499.0
7    2997.5
8     749.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

y me gustaría predecir el próximo período usando ARIMA:

```
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt

array = []

for i, row in test.iterrows():
  print("row['shop_id']: ", row['shop_id'], " row['item_id']: ", row['item_id'])
  ts = pd.DataFrame(sales_monthly.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, [row['shop_id']],[row['item_id']]], :]['item_price'].values*sales_monthly.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, [row['shop_id']],[row['item_id']]], :]['item_cnt_day'].values).T.iloc[0]
  rng = range(5)
  for i in rng:
    for j in rng:
      try:
        tmp_mdl = smt.ARMA(ts, order = (i, j)).fit(method='mle', trand='nc')
        tmp_aic = tmp_mdl.aic
        if tmp_aic < best_aic:
          best_aic = tmp_aic
          best_order = (i, j)
          best_mdl = tmp_mdl
      except:
        continue
  if best_mdl.predict()<0:
    y_pred = 0
  else:
    y_pred = best_mdl.predict()
  d = {'id':row['ID'], 'item_cnt_month': y_pred}
  array.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df
```

Pero obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-85dfa2fa67c1> in <module>()
     22       except:
     23         continue
---> 24   if best_mdl.predict()<0:
     25     y_pred = 0
     26   else:

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in geterrors(self, params)
    686             k = self.k_exog + self.k_trend
    687             if k > 0:
--> 688                 y -= dot(self.exog, params[:k])
    689 
    690             k_ar = self.k_ar

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Entonces intenté con `best_mdl.predict().astype('float32')` pero no cambia nada.

Answer (score 0):

Voy por partes:

### Modelo

En tu pregunta dices:

> me gustaría predecir el próximo período usando ARIMA

Pero luego usas `smt.ARMA` que es un modelo **ARMA**. Estos modelos son parecidos, pero distintos, **partiendo del nombre**:

- *ARMA* = *Autoregressive Moving Average*.
- *ARIMA* = *Autorgressive **Integrated** Moving Average*

El modelo **ARMA** tiene 2 parámetros (p,q):

- *p*: la parte autoregresiva (AR) que generar predicciones usando los valores anteriores.
- *q*: la parte que mueve las medias (MA = Moving Average) y hace predicciones usando las medias y el error previo

El modelo **ARIMA** tiene un parámetros más (p,d,q):

- *d*: se refiere a la **diferenciación**, es el **número de veces que necesitas diferenciar una serie para consegir la estacionalidad**

Basicamente si ponemos el parámetros *d* del modelo **ARIMA** a cero, tenemos el modelo **ARMA**

ARMA(p,q) == ARIMA(P,0,q)

Te dejo la documentación de todo lo que te he dicho y más por si quieres ampliar:

[Documentación ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average)

[Documentación ARMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model)

[Proceso estacionario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)

### Problema

Tu problema es que **no estás pasandole ningún parámetro a la predicción** por tanto el método `.predict()` no sabe que predecir. Le tienes que pasar el inicio y el final de la predicción, por ejemplo:

```
best_mdl.predict(10, 20)
```

Dependerá de como tengas tus datos, por ejemplo si son fechas

```
#Que prediga todo el año 2018
best_mdl.predict("2018", "2019")
```

Este problema lo tienes en estas lineas:

```
  if best_mdl.predict()<0: #AQUÍ
    y_pred = 0
  else:
    y_pred = best_mdl.predict() #AQUÍ
```